# How to have a NSTextView with a different font size just for printing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextview that only shows good when the text is set to at least 16 in size, but that is too big for printing. How to have a NSTextView with a different font size just for printing ? I have digged into NSPrintInfo but got no result so far. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
// Create another text view just for printing
var printTextView = NSTextView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 528, 688)) // A4
// Add a modified version of your attributed string to the view
printTextView.textStorage!.mutableString.appendString(myAttributedStringWithAdjustedSize)
// Get printing infos
let sharedInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()
let sharedDict = sharedInfo.dictionary()
let printInfoDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: sharedDict)
printInfoDict.setObject(NSPrintSpoolJob, forKey: NSPrintJobDisposition)
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printInfoDict)
// Set some preferences
printInfo.horizontallyCentered = true
printInfo.verticallyCentered = false
printInfo.scalingFactor = 0.8
// Print the custom text view
let op = NSPrintOperation(view: printTextView, printInfo: printInfo)
op.runOperation()
```

Comment: I just realized you wanted Objective-C code, sorry for the Swift. I'll remove my answer if it's not useful to you.