# Print a view with images and text

Tags: macos, printing, swiftui

I have spent some hours reading Google and Stack Overflow on this, the result is an increase in bafflement!

I would have thought what I am trying to do would be easy.

I have a view that includes a background image and overlayed text (its a certificate) that needs to be printed. I have the view displayed, now need to print.

I have tried following [macOS Printing in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930873/macos-printing-in-swift)
and to get the window [How to access own window within SwiftUI view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359808/how-to-access-own-window-within-swiftui-view)

The app is OSX desktop Swift and Xcode etc all latest versions.

I would post sample code but I am at a loss as at what wat to do it. Do I need the host window? Do I need to create a view just for the print? Do I need NSPrintOperation?

Many thanks.

Comment: I have got partway there, actually getting something out on the printer!

Text not quite aligned as I would like but I think I know how to solve that.

The big issue now is that the background image is not printed.

Code I am using is as follows:

 @IBAction func print2(_ sender : Any){
        let printingView = self.window.contentView
        let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: printingView!, printInfo: NSPrintInfo())
        printOperation.showsPrintPanel = true
        printOperation.showsProgressPanel = true
        printOperation.run()
    }

Any ideas?